# Is there still support for favicons in react using Firefox?

Tags: html, reactjs, firefox, icons, favicon

Trying to host a react app on github pages but when the website opens in Firefox the favicon will not show up.

Tried resetting cache and browser and use multiple variations of the code below but still will not show.

Used https://convertio.co/png-ico/ for making the ico file. Does anyone know what is going on ? This works perfectly on chrome etc.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" />
```

Comment: Probably the path is wrong

Comment: "/images/favicon.ico" is where my icon is. I've also tried "./images/favicon.ico" as well as moving my icon to the public folder and just having "./favicon.ico". What else can I try do you think ?